# Limit RAM and CPU use for a python script

Tags: python, cpu, ram

I run several python script on a linux server with lots of RAM and CPU cores. How could I specify a maximum number of RAM and a maximum number of CPU cores for each of them ? I could use linux bash scripts or python code to achieve this.

Answer (score 10):

You can use Linux command **nice** to choose the priority that you want on your process.

```
nice -n 10 python yourScript.py
```

Positive number gives less priority to the process.

**-20** is the most favorable to the process and **19** is the least favorable to the process.

This will avoid to have a process consuming all your CPU when other process need it.

For the RAM you can use the command **ulimit** which allow to limit resources.

```
Limit the RAM to 1GB (1000000 number is in kB)
ulimit -m 1000000 && python yourScript.py
```

You can check actual limit in your shell with option *-a*.

Comment: use `-v` instead of `-m` flag.
[check link](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/ulimit.def)